# What filter settings to play with to achieve for tinted vintage matte feel photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

My desired effect is [image]

I have some normal plain photos that I want to convert to achieve a similar tone / feel. I am fairly new to Photoshop and I know I have to play with the saturation(?) to get this. What other settings should I be using to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using colored layers, it is 100% nondestructive:

1. On the top of the layer stack, add a Photo Filter adjustment layer
2. Choose the color you like, make sure to have a check mark in the box next to "Preserve Luminosity" option
3. Adjust "Density" to taste
4. You can change the color by clicking on the "Color" if you like instead of using a pre set photo filter
5. Optionally, you can also adjust the opacity of this layer

An alternative to using a photo filter is:

1. Add a blank layer at the top of the stack
2. Fill it with a color you like, something like sepia or selenium which is somewhere between blue and purple
3. Change the blend mode to "Hue"
4. Adjust layer opacity to taste

In either case, you can drag this layer from one image to another to apply the same effect, thus maintaining a unified look. Take a look at the screen capture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Image menu there is a tool called match color (**Image → Adjustments → Match Colors**). It tries to match the color of one image (or selection thereof) with another image. Splitting your images off and using the first image as a source for the others with.

[image]

**Image 1**: After matching all images with leftmost image, uisng 15% fade and 80-90% Intensity settings.

#### Resources:

- [Matching Colors Of Objects Between Photos With Photoshop](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/match-color/)